# Deploying a Spring Boot web application as a service to Ubuntu

Tags: java, services

I have a Spring Boot app that I want to start using `System V Init`. My jar file is in `/var/my-app/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. So, I created a symbolic link using the command below

```
sudo ln -s /var/my-app/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /etc/init.d/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

without any issue. However, when I try

```
sudo service my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT start
```

I get the error:

```
/etc/init.d/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 1: /etc/init.d/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it might help someone else in the future, I managed to get this to work using `upstart`. Original answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401930/deploying-a-spring-boot-web-application-as-a-service-to-ubuntu/48404470#48404470).

I'm going to copy and paste the answer by Patrk Bego here for convenience:

You will first have to define the Upstart script (in case of Ubuntu 14.04 ), it is in /etc/init/ and ending in .conf. (http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/)

```
# <service name>.conf
start on filesystem
exec /usr/bin/java -jar /path_to/program
```

in case of Ubuntu 16.06+ (you can find nice article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401930/deploying-a-spring-boot-web-application-as-a-service-to-ubuntu/48404470#48404470))

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/my-webapp.service
```

Then you can run it as:

```
sudo service <your service name> start
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu uses systemd. You can find a post of someone asking a similar question in this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320314/configure-java-daemon-with-systemd)

Another approach would be to use some orchestration tool like kubernetes or docker swarm to create services that can rerun the service even if it fails at some point of time.

An example with docker:

In your `Dockerfile`

```
FROM java:8-jre-alpine
COPY /location/of/your/jar/xyz.jar /where/you/want/it/stored/xyz.jar
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "java -jar /where/you/want/it/stored/xyz.jar"]
```

Build your docker image

```
docker build \
   -t my-app:0.0.1-snapshot \ #specify a name for your image
   /dockerfile/location/      # the location of your dockerfile
```

To test

```
docker run -it \           # -it represents interactive tty
   -p 80:8080 \            # -p binds 8080 (the container port) to 80 (host port)
   --restart=always \      # --restart=always run the service unless stopped by user
   --name my-app \         # --name the name of your container
   my-app:0.0.1-snapshot   # the image you built with the build command
```

Test with postman or browser to your localhost.
You can try restarting your computer and the application should still run.
In production, you'd use swarm or kubernetes.

To use swarm, you create a `docker-compose.yml` file and you should store your images on a registry - a built image must exist on the managing node if it's not pushed to a registry.

In your `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  my-app:
    image: my-app:0.0.1-snapshot
    ports: 
      - "80:8080"
    restart: always
```

In terminal:

```
docker swarm init
docker stack deploy my-app --compose-file ./docker-compose.yml
```

You should check out their [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/) for other matters like persistence and security.